# Проблемы с установкой libtorch (pytorch c++)

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch

Я скачал Cuda toolkit 12.1 , как и каталог libtorch  и проблем не возникает, Cmake тоже. Действую согласно руководству на сайте https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html, ошибок после `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\libtorch ..` не возникает
выдает следующее:

```
PS C:\example-app\build> cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\libtorch ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32825.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32825.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1 (found version "12.1") 
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 12.1.66
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/bin/nvcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CUDA compile features
-- Detecting CUDA compile features - done
-- Found CUDAToolkit: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include (found version "12.1.66") 
-- Caffe2: CUDA detected: 12.1
-- Caffe2: CUDA nvcc is: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/bin/nvcc.exe
-- Caffe2: CUDA toolkit directory: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1
-- Caffe2: Header version is: 12.1
-- C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/lib/x64/nvrtc.lib shorthash is bac8224f
-- USE_CUDNN is set to 0. Compiling without cuDNN support
-- USE_CUSPARSELT is set to 0. Compiling without cuSPARSELt support
-- Autodetected CUDA architecture(s):  7.5
-- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: -gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75
-- Found Torch: C:/libtorch/lib/torch.lib  
-- Configuring done (19.4s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/example-app/build
```

но когда печатаю команду cmake --build . --config Release
вместо этого :

```
Scanning dependencies of target example-app
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example-app.dir/example-app.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable example-app
[100%] Built target example-app
```

выдает это и прежде долго выполняет команду

```
Версия MSBuild 17.7.2+d6990bcfa для .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/example-app/CMakeLists.txt
  example-app.cpp
     Создается библиотека C:/example-app/build/Release/example-app.lib и объект C:/example-app/build/Release/example-app.exp
  example-app.vcxproj -> C:\example-app\build\Release\example-app.exe
  Building Custom Rule C:/example-app/CMakeLists.txt
```

Помогите мне пожалуйста, не могу найти решение больше месяца

Comment: Я запускаю через командную строку команду C:/example-app/build/Release/example-app.exe
, которая выводит необходимый тензор, теперь вопрос, правильно это или нет, если да, то что делать дальше?